# How to clean up folders efficiently using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am using a directory structure with various folders. There are new files created daily in some of them.

I have created some programs to clean up the directories, but I would like to use a shell script to make it more efficient.

Therefore I would like to store an "**archiving.properties**" file in every folder that needs to be cleaned up. The properties file should contain the following variables

```
file_pattern="*.xml"
days_to_keep=2
```

Now my clean up routine should:

1. find all properties files
2. delete all files that match the file name pattern (file_pattern) and that are older then the defined number of days (days_to_keep) in the directory where the properties file was found.

So my question is how can I do this in the most efficient way?

```
find . -type f -name "archiving.properties"  -print
find . -type f -name "<file_pattern>"  -mtime +<days_to_keep> -delete
```

currently I was trying the following in a single folder. It prints out the command correctly, but it is not executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
. archiving.properties
find . -type f -name "*.xml"  -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
echo "    find . -type f -name \"${file_pattern}\"  -mtime +${days_to_keep} -exec rm -rf {} \;" 


Result is:    find . -type f -name "*.xml"  -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Forget for a moment operating on an entire directory tree; if you have a single directory containing your proposed `archive.properties` file, have you considered how you would handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I got a final result

```
echo "start deleting files in " $(pwd) " ... "

#filename of the properties
properties="clean_up.properties"

#find all properties files
for prop in $(find . -type f -name $properties);do
        #init variables
        file_pattern="*._html"
        days_to_keep=14

        #load the variables from the properties file
        . "$prop"

        #define the folder of the properties file
        folder=${prop%?$properties}

        #remove all files matching the parameters in the folder where the properties were found
        echo ">>>   find $folder -type f -name \"${file_pattern}\" -mtime +${days_to_keep} -exec rm -f {} \;"
                    find $folder -type f -name "${file_pattern}"   -mtime +${days_to_keep} -exec rm -f {} \;
done
echo "... done"
```